# Are these commas a proper way to indicate pauses in speech?

Tags: commas

> One site was a community of computer technicians, and the other, our government’s.

I checked for answer in the usual [list of comma rules](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/commas.htm).

Comment: Nothing wrong or unprescriptive, if you keep the sentence as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comma usage is fine.

The problem I have with your sentence is that you have made it so concise that it's difficult to parse your intended meaning.

I assume that what you mean to say is the following:

> One site was a community of computer technicians, and the other site was our government’s.

Is the saving of two words really worth the opacity of the syntax?

Comment: +1. The original sentence is indeed quite unclear. Was the other site the government’s site? Or the government’s community? (The government’s computer technicians, even?)

Answer (score 0):

Using the quite interesting resources you cited, *Rules for Comma Usage*, [I believe your answer is hidden in example 7](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/commas.htm#7): Use commas to set off phrases that express contrast.

You are succinctly contrasting two sites, but the contrast is not as obvious as the examples in the resource: fire and ice or cute and messy. The contrast does not have to be in opposition, it must merely be different.

If you were to remove the second comma, I would replace it with "was" because then the two clauses would mirror each other in structure.

I will admit a little uncertainty, however, about the first comma because it precedes a conjunction and implies that "the other, our government’s." is an independent clause. Forced to choose, I would omit the first comma because I feel that the second clause cannot stand on its own.

I do believe, however, that the sentence as written is unambiguous and concise. I also believe that removing the first comma would not increase the ambiguity or hurt the meter of the sentence.